# I keep getting error in knitting r markdown notebook

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Good day, the sample code below is my Google Data analytics Capstone project and while the codes run perfectly in R studio, but ths code chunk:

```
all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$from_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0), ]
```

throws up error and halt the execution of the R Markdown notebook

````
---
title: "Google Data Analytics"
author: "ifechi mafiana"
date: "2022-12-26"
output: html_document
---


## Cyclistic Bike analysis
**The plots of the Cyclistic bike rides data analysis shows the comparison between annual members and casual riders bike usage**


### Setting up my environment

```{r set up environment}
# setwd("C:/Users/olatu/Documents/R Programming/Cyclistic_tripdata")
```

```{r load packages}
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
```

### Collect Data and Upload data

```{r load 12 months tripdata}
# Use first 100 rows of data from Dec 2021 file 
theData <- "ride_id,rideable_type,started_at,ended_at,start_station_name,start_station_id,end_station_name,end_station_id,start_lat,start_lng,end_lat,end_lng,member_casual
46F8167220E4431F,electric_bike,2021-12-07 15:06:07,2021-12-07 15:13:42,Laflin St & Cullerton St,13307,Morgan St & Polk St,TA1307000130,41.854833,-87.66366033333334,41.8719685,-87.65096533333333,member
73A77762838B32FD,electric_bike,2021-12-11 03:43:29,2021-12-11 04:10:23,LaSalle Dr & Huron St,KP1705001026,Clarendon Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000119,41.894405166666665,-87.632331,41.967968,-87.650001,casual
4CF42452054F59C5,electric_bike,2021-12-15 23:10:28,2021-12-15 23:23:14,Halsted St & North Branch St,KA1504000117,Broadway & Barry Ave,13137,41.89935716666667,-87.64852183333333,41.93758231600629,-87.6440978050232,member
3278BA87BF698339,classic_bike,2021-12-26 16:16:10,2021-12-26 16:30:53,Halsted St & North Branch St,KA1504000117,LaSalle Dr & Huron St,KP1705001026,41.89939028549696,-87.64854490756989,41.894877,-87.632326,member
6FF54232576A3B73,electric_bike,2021-12-30 11:31:05,2021-12-30 11:51:21,Leavitt St & Chicago Ave,18058,Clark St & Drummond Pl,TA1307000142,41.89557883333333,-87.68202383333333,41.931248,-87.644336,member
93E8D79490E3AB11,classic_bike,2021-12-01 18:28:36,2021-12-01 18:38:03,Wabash Ave & 16th St,SL-012,Wells St & Polk St,SL-011,41.860384,-87.625813,41.872596,-87.633502,member
135518383C9CACF0,electric_bike,2021-12-09 15:49:51,2021-12-09 15:55:49,Laflin St & Cullerton St,13307,Halsted St & Maxwell St,TA1309000001,41.8548755,-87.66365216666667,41.86482733333333,-87.64709983333333,member
CDF93C212EA9B261,classic_bike,2021-12-31 13:02:08,2021-12-31 13:20:59,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Ashland Ave & Lake St,13073,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.88592,-87.66717,casual
0FCA94C5F26535C8,electric_bike,2021-12-20 14:25:53,2021-12-20 14:35:48,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Ogden Ave & Chicago Ave,TA1305000020,41.885915518,-87.631485343,41.896362458,-87.6540612729,member
8E913048B7BCAA47,classic_bike,2021-12-19 16:58:32,2021-12-19 17:15:01,Fairbanks St & Superior St,18003,Lincoln Park Conservatory,LP-,41.895748,-87.620104,41.92393131136619,-87.63582453131676,member
E3689BB4C54E030A,classic_bike,2021-12-29 10:40:44,2021-12-29 11:01:45,Michigan Ave & 18th St,13150,Michigan Ave & 18th St,13150,41.857813,-87.62455,41.857813,-87.62455,member
293B0FE2F7F99DE2,electric_bike,2021-12-21 12:05:20,2021-12-21 12:08:10,Dearborn St & Van Buren St,624,Dearborn St & Van Buren St,624,41.876252651,-87.629443526,41.876268,-87.629155,member
E02FB049C19238C7,classic_bike,2021-12-14 08:07:53,2021-12-14 08:13:06,LaSalle Dr & Huron St,KP1705001026,Rush St & Hubbard St,KA1503000044,41.894877,-87.632326,41.890173,-87.626185,casual
5907837A6F7AA0B7,electric_bike,2021-12-22 08:40:41,2021-12-22 08:43:40,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,Clark St & Touhy Ave,RP-007,42.012708,-87.66613566666666,42.01256011541,-87.6743671152,casual
A9765C45F5C7571B,classic_bike,2021-12-17 08:46:26,2021-12-17 08:50:18,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,Clark St & Touhy Ave,RP-007,42.012701,-87.666058,42.01256011541,-87.6743671152,casual
AFFEDF52749D0EE5,classic_bike,2021-12-06 08:44:04,2021-12-06 08:48:36,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,Clark St & Touhy Ave,RP-007,42.012701,-87.666058,42.01256011541,-87.6743671152,casual
403B1425A552627A,electric_bike,2021-12-03 08:46:31,2021-12-03 08:48:40,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,Clark St & Touhy Ave,RP-007,42.01278633333333,-87.66606166666666,42.0126045,-87.674227,casual
1F890212968B33FD,classic_bike,2021-12-18 09:17:17,2021-12-18 09:29:05,Wells St & Huron St,TA1306000012,Aberdeen St & Monroe St,13156,41.894722,-87.634362,41.880419,-87.655519,member
F05028CCBDD22947,docked_bike,2021-12-04 11:44:37,2021-12-04 11:57:54,Wilton Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1307000134,Halsted St & Roscoe St,TA1309000025,41.94018,-87.65304,41.94367,-87.64895,casual
B55A7BFC64E93A57,electric_bike,2021-12-08 09:34:04,2021-12-08 09:41:01,Wilton Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1307000134,Halsted St & Roscoe St,TA1309000025,41.94008016666667,-87.65298683333333,41.94372083333333,-87.64885633333333,member
A97968863BBCE05C,classic_bike,2021-12-09 16:01:07,2021-12-09 16:21:01,Aberdeen St & Randolph St,18062,Walsh Park,18067,41.884114,-87.654264,41.91461,-87.667968,member
E07A177659BC448F,electric_bike,2021-12-11 17:08:07,2021-12-11 17:15:10,Dodge Ave & Church St,600,Evanston Civic Center,661,42.04830366666667,-87.69849883333333,42.057044,-87.686554,casual
2B5A05BD74955D2A,classic_bike,2021-12-10 08:48:55,2021-12-10 08:52:31,Federal St & Polk St,SL-008,Wabash Ave & Roosevelt Rd,TA1305000002,41.87207763285,-87.6295437729,41.867227,-87.625961,member
50A1154F93E6A55E,electric_bike,2021-12-25 08:48:36,2021-12-25 09:15:09,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,Clinton St & Jackson Blvd,638,41.90043033333333,-87.69670666666667,41.878316611830684,-87.64098107814789,member
A470CE16359A50A2,classic_bike,2021-12-18 19:32:39,2021-12-18 19:38:48,Fairbanks St & Superior St,18003,New St & Illinois St,TA1306000013,41.895748,-87.620104,41.890847040623804,-87.61861681938171,member
0FB2A64EE77B56E7,classic_bike,2021-12-11 23:25:56,2021-12-11 23:47:48,Dodge Ave & Church St,600,Oakley Ave & Touhy Ave,RP-004,42.048308,-87.698224,42.012342,-87.688243,member
E7E15D54DD72AC73,electric_bike,2021-12-03 19:34:27,2021-12-03 19:48:21,N Green St & W Lake St,20246.0,Damen Ave & Wabansia Ave,20.0,41.89,-87.65,41.91,-87.68,casual
4D83C1605F5F918E,electric_bike,2021-12-29 11:48:18,2021-12-29 12:00:59,State St & Pearson St,TA1307000061,N Carpenter St & W Lake St,20251.0,41.897466,-87.62874716666667,41.89,-87.65,casual
06A16531D95759A1,classic_bike,2021-12-14 18:55:01,2021-12-14 18:58:01,Wilton Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1307000134,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.94018,-87.65304,41.94454,-87.654678,member
28C14B8496B5DD70,electric_bike,2021-12-29 20:25:09,2021-12-29 21:12:03,Lake Park Ave & 56th St,TA1309000063,MLK Jr Dr & 47th St,TA1308000007,41.793267166666666,-87.58784083333333,41.809851,-87.616279,member
8ACF980C651AB448,classic_bike,2021-12-09 20:19:40,2021-12-09 20:33:22,Halsted St & Wrightwood Ave,TA1309000061,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.929143,-87.649077,41.94454,-87.654678,member
D1910A373A3A0BB9,classic_bike,2021-12-10 02:20:46,2021-12-10 02:25:28,Sheffield Ave & Wellington Ave,TA1307000052,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.9362534831413,-87.65266209840775,41.94454,-87.654678,member
9BA29005E96FCC49,classic_bike,2021-12-04 17:20:51,2021-12-04 17:31:33,Lincoln Ave & Waveland Ave,13253,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.948797,-87.675278,41.94454,-87.654678,member
AC31CCD9B07FF5F9,classic_bike,2021-12-04 21:34:55,2021-12-04 21:44:55,Lincoln Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1309000042,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.939365,-87.668385,41.94454,-87.654678,casual
CC027A7D6A217B97,electric_bike,2021-12-05 10:39:16,2021-12-05 10:44:49,Loomis St & Jackson Blvd,13206,Wood St & Taylor St (Temp),13285,41.877955166666666,-87.66199466666667,41.87000616666667,-87.67378283333333,member
0F548320DAB8D329,electric_bike,2021-12-13 11:02:49,2021-12-13 11:14:54,Fairbanks St & Superior St,18003,Streeter Dr & Grand Ave,13022,41.896165833333335,-87.62022,41.892278,-87.612043,casual
4B67968FF3B2B856,classic_bike,2021-12-01 00:28:14,2021-12-01 00:45:56,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Calumet Ave & 21st St,15546,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.85418424947,-87.6191537415,casual
13ECACF914AD20A1,electric_bike,2021-12-09 18:08:46,2021-12-09 18:20:55,State St & Pearson St,TA1307000061,Streeter Dr & Grand Ave,13022,41.89745466666667,-87.62857033333333,41.892278,-87.612043,casual
8B2078CF8767BC69,classic_bike,2021-12-20 09:35:37,2021-12-20 09:46:30,Wabash Ave & 16th St,SL-012,LaSalle St & Washington St,13006,41.860384,-87.625813,41.882664,-87.63253,member
3DCFF37E2BEDCEAA,electric_bike,2021-12-10 10:34:26,2021-12-10 10:42:30,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,,,42.0128285,-87.66592533333333,42.0,-87.66,member
8F0F71A8AB4D31CE,electric_bike,2021-12-03 17:27:21,2021-12-03 17:36:48,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,,,42.01275316666667,-87.66610816666666,42.0,-87.66,casual
89AD350CD31D0510,classic_bike,2021-12-13 11:47:12,2021-12-13 11:58:42,Broadway & Granville Ave,15571,Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave,TA1308000021,41.9947796884,-87.6602845349,41.968812,-87.657659,member
CDA946785B295248,classic_bike,2021-12-06 08:58:57,2021-12-06 09:07:53,Wabash Ave & 16th St,SL-012,Michigan Ave & 14th St,TA1307000124,41.860384,-87.625813,41.864059,-87.623727,member
A4A59AAD9459329F,classic_bike,2021-12-19 11:03:13,2021-12-19 11:11:29,Southport Ave & Clybourn Ave,TA1309000030,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.920771,-87.663712,41.9256018819,-87.6537080423,member
6ECCE59D288A5CCF,classic_bike,2021-12-19 11:40:19,2021-12-19 11:48:14,Southport Ave & Clybourn Ave,TA1309000030,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.920771,-87.663712,41.9256018819,-87.6537080423,member
8C4488C4A94BB147,electric_bike,2021-12-20 13:34:41,2021-12-20 14:07:08,Aberdeen St & Monroe St,13156,Central Park Ave & Ogden Ave,15685,41.880546808,-87.655724049,41.854063503874464,-87.71511733531952,member
6A96D37D4F39C586,classic_bike,2021-12-16 08:16:33,2021-12-16 08:25:27,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Canal St & Madison St,13341,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.882091,-87.639833,member
24BB294225E94AC1,classic_bike,2021-12-20 15:11:04,2021-12-20 15:20:06,Campbell Ave & Montrose Ave,15623,Washtenaw Ave & Lawrence Ave,KA1504000080,41.96152593287,-87.6911650414,41.968987,-87.696027,member
90FA2B7BB19CF096,classic_bike,2021-12-29 20:11:00,2021-12-29 20:43:57,Canal St & Monroe St,13056,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.88169,-87.63953,41.9256018819,-87.6537080423,member
657E9CFD79B95AE8,electric_bike,2021-12-02 00:51:09,2021-12-02 01:04:05,N Green St & W Lake St,20246.0,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.89,-87.65,41.925649,-87.65371683333333,casual
D3632D691E8F813C,electric_bike,2021-12-04 13:06:46,2021-12-04 13:10:53,Burling St & Diversey Pkwy,TA1309000036,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.93305766666667,-87.64765216666666,41.925556666666665,-87.6536585,member
98F5A6F00C8555F2,electric_bike,2021-12-03 17:20:26,2021-12-03 17:25:23,Ashland Ave & Wrightwood Ave,13296,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.9288585,-87.66863883333333,41.925589,-87.65368433333333,member
B91BB790F7579041,classic_bike,2021-12-24 11:06:26,2021-12-24 11:12:43,Southport Ave & Clybourn Ave,TA1309000030,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.920771,-87.663712,41.9256018819,-87.6537080423,casual
1CF72E362EFE630D,electric_bike,2021-12-06 13:02:00,2021-12-06 13:11:11,Lincoln Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1309000042,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.939370394,-87.668308496,41.967056394,-87.679019332,casual
0221F6E40799B545,electric_bike,2021-12-18 22:51:12,2021-12-18 22:58:52,Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave,TA1308000021,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.9688455,-87.65766416666666,41.967094,-87.679028,member
011DA6BBC01F7E4D,classic_bike,2021-12-15 17:24:27,2021-12-15 17:40:10,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Michigan Ave & 14th St,TA1307000124,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.864059,-87.623727,member
CEFAFD7AFF3196EE,classic_bike,2021-12-26 14:46:11,2021-12-26 15:08:52,Lakefront Trail & Bryn Mawr Ave,KA1504000152,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.98403669612,-87.6523104689,41.967094,-87.679028,casual
F6CBEFD434F8E287,classic_bike,2021-12-18 22:40:14,2021-12-18 23:01:50,Clark St & Newport St,632,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.94454,-87.654678,41.967094,-87.679028,casual
610FFD9351696397,classic_bike,2021-12-27 15:29:05,2021-12-27 16:26:10,Walsh Park,18067,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.91461,-87.667968,41.967094,-87.679028,casual
7176000CF625B000,classic_bike,2021-12-15 20:36:45,2021-12-15 20:56:54,Latrobe Ave & Chicago Ave,642,Latrobe Ave & Chicago Ave,642,41.894745,-87.756895,41.894745,-87.756895,casual
6122422CF59F1F67,electric_bike,2021-12-12 14:09:44,2021-12-12 14:50:15,2112 W Peterson Ave,KA1504000155,2112 W Peterson Ave,KA1504000155,41.99112733333333,-87.68361483333334,41.991178,-87.683593,casual
5FCDBE49D4E0C200,classic_bike,2021-12-12 13:12:48,2021-12-12 13:37:31,Kildare Ave & Montrose Ave,KA1706005015,Wolcott (Ravenswood) Ave & Montrose Ave,TA1307000144,41.96108,-87.73569,41.961406,-87.676169,casual
21E8C75412330B79,electric_bike,2021-12-14 17:50:19,2021-12-14 18:16:13,N Carpenter St & W Lake St,20251.0,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.89,-87.65,41.900363,-87.696704,casual
1DEF50889E9AEBAA,electric_bike,2021-12-03 16:35:36,2021-12-03 16:56:21,Damen Ave & Grand Ave,TA1308000006,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.89127383333334,-87.67688483333333,41.90031033333333,-87.696708,member
C52AE4225D48325D,electric_bike,2021-12-04 08:01:57,2021-12-04 08:14:05,Emerald Ave & 28th St,TA1307000153,Hoyne Ave & 34th St,337,41.84358666666667,-87.6454565,41.83,-87.68,member
B5B219C88CA6AF2E,classic_bike,2021-12-10 13:41:52,2021-12-10 13:54:44,Elizabeth St & 59th St,647,Ashland Ave & 66th St,16950,41.789696880483376,-87.65469789505005,41.774074,-87.663815,member
94F6992B0BDFAAA1,electric_bike,2021-12-03 20:16:01,2021-12-03 20:33:14,Orleans St & Chestnut St (NEXT Apts),620,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.898133333333334,-87.63740616666666,41.900313,-87.69669016666667,member
6AC61ECBD3F40AC3,electric_bike,2021-12-17 23:28:12,2021-12-17 23:31:54,Leavitt St & Division St,658,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.903012333333336,-87.68369916666667,41.900363,-87.696704,member
1C74CD5B7E1ACB16,electric_bike,2021-12-18 18:28:09,2021-12-18 18:50:41,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.8859895,-87.63141283333333,41.900363,-87.696704,casual
86115CC031D84228,electric_bike,2021-12-17 08:00:01,2021-12-17 08:20:28,Sheffield Ave & Wellington Ave,TA1307000052,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.936349869,-87.652525187,41.900363,-87.696704,casual
9782815F2CC9E24F,classic_bike,2021-12-10 08:12:44,2021-12-10 08:22:28,Honore St & Division St,TA1305000034,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.903119,-87.673935,41.900363,-87.696704,member
120241F9439BE1B9,classic_bike,2021-12-02 12:11:45,2021-12-02 12:28:19,Laflin St & Cullerton St,13307,Halsted St & Roosevelt Rd,TA1305000017,41.85491457576575,-87.66355991363525,41.867324,-87.648625,member
41AC50E187DE1A86,classic_bike,2021-12-06 14:04:57,2021-12-06 14:07:51,Aberdeen St & Monroe St,13156,Green St & Madison St,TA1307000120,41.880419,-87.655519,41.881892,-87.648789,member
65F507B9C9FED0B5,classic_bike,2021-12-24 12:50:14,2021-12-24 12:51:43,State St & Randolph St,TA1305000029,Daley Center Plaza,TA1306000010,41.88462107257936,-87.62783423066139,41.884241,-87.629634,member
A42CBACBBB0A5F27,electric_bike,2021-12-23 13:06:11,2021-12-23 13:07:38,State St & Randolph St,TA1305000029,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.884563,-87.627875,41.884576228,-87.63188991,member
C50FCC0636821A77,electric_bike,2021-12-21 14:25:47,2021-12-21 14:46:51,Laflin St & Cullerton St,13307,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.85482283333333,-87.66370816666667,41.884576228,-87.63188991,casual
86A06B8C23F54400,electric_bike,2021-12-01 20:16:23,2021-12-01 20:25:19,Wells St & Huron St,TA1306000012,Green St & Madison St,TA1307000120,41.89496416666667,-87.6343905,41.88212883333333,-87.6487835,member
21E3BD0217503F94,electric_bike,2021-12-13 09:07:29,2021-12-13 09:13:36,State St & Pearson St,TA1307000061,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.89708233333333,-87.628757,41.884576228,-87.63188991,member
BA5A950CEDA7D465,classic_bike,2021-12-15 17:12:23,2021-12-15 17:13:39,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.884576228,-87.63188991,casual
DF6553F5009A743C,electric_bike,2021-12-09 06:32:42,2021-12-09 06:45:26,Washtenaw Ave & Ogden Ave,KA1504000109,Green St & Madison St,TA1307000120,41.86187916666667,-87.6935635,41.881781833333335,-87.64908066666666,casual
48C9ACB2054E5DC5,electric_bike,2021-12-07 18:52:54,2021-12-07 18:56:50,LaSalle St & Washington St,13006,Green St & Madison St,TA1307000120,41.882658166666666,-87.63257866666666,41.881865166666664,-87.648443,member
B6DE20D10BB7F2A2,classic_bike,2021-12-07 08:14:49,2021-12-07 08:21:15,Columbus Dr & Randolph St,13263,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.884728,-87.619521,41.884576228,-87.63188991,member
E9BDAA92128EB17A,docked_bike,2021-12-14 11:16:15,2021-12-14 11:24:25,Indiana Ave & Roosevelt Rd,SL-005,State St & Van Buren St,TA1305000035,41.867888,-87.623041,41.877181,-87.627844,casual
2318305579BEF4BC,electric_bike,2021-12-01 13:12:17,2021-12-01 13:18:45,N Green St & W Lake St,20246.0,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.89,-87.65,41.88519133333333,-87.63171466666667,member
CBCCD6345A1A04C1,electric_bike,2021-12-16 17:10:14,2021-12-16 17:24:01,Milwaukee Ave & Grand Ave,13033,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.891658,-87.64808316666667,41.900363,-87.696704,member
620201B2E4B4A936,electric_bike,2021-12-27 05:34:05,2021-12-27 05:55:53,Clark St & Newport St,632,McClurg Ct & Erie St,KA1503000041,41.94457666666667,-87.65482666666666,41.894503,-87.617854,member
B40421B9789D7A9D,electric_bike,2021-12-21 05:36:34,2021-12-21 05:41:52,Halsted St & North Branch St,KA1504000117,Halsted St & Clybourn Ave,331,41.89932683333333,-87.64850733333333,41.909668,-87.648128,casual
48FEC42831404CCC,classic_bike,2021-12-07 22:58:33,2021-12-07 23:07:12,Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave,TA1308000021,Broadway & Ridge Ave,15578,41.968812,-87.657659,41.9840446107,-87.6602738295,member
744D14BD03CEB1E8,classic_bike,2021-12-14 16:03:08,2021-12-14 16:08:34,Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave,TA1308000021,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.968812,-87.657659,41.978353,-87.659753,member
CD9E7DF9BE191A94,electric_bike,2021-12-18 12:32:00,2021-12-18 12:59:49,Fairbanks St & Superior St,18003,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.8957795,-87.62063883333333,41.978353,-87.659753,member
DAFFB8138DA2B444,classic_bike,2021-12-05 10:06:32,2021-12-05 10:30:59,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,Broadway & Ridge Ave,15578,41.967094,-87.679028,41.9840446107,-87.6602738295,casual
14CF12D2CC28AFDD,classic_bike,2021-12-15 20:24:34,2021-12-15 20:48:42,Clark St & Newport St,632,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.94454,-87.654678,41.978353,-87.659753,casual
D6CDF4784BD2C926,electric_bike,2021-12-31 12:27:08,2021-12-31 12:34:26,Sheridan Rd & Montrose Ave,TA1307000107,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.961522333333335,-87.654598,41.978353,-87.659753,member
A09709F0C2EBC78B,classic_bike,2021-12-05 17:40:26,2021-12-05 17:47:59,Clarendon Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000119,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.967968,-87.650001,41.978353,-87.659753,member
EE59FE91B61BCCC8,classic_bike,2021-12-19 11:12:34,2021-12-19 11:16:07,Clark St & Berwyn Ave,KA1504000146,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.978030622486564,-87.66856491565704,41.978353,-87.659753,member
1293FC6A35A690EB,classic_bike,2021-12-16 06:22:43,2021-12-16 06:25:17,Clark St & Berwyn Ave,KA1504000146,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.978030622486564,-87.66856491565704,41.978353,-87.659753,member
3CBE482E55A4F4A6,classic_bike,2021-12-13 07:26:13,2021-12-13 08:05:11,State St & Pearson St,TA1307000061,Wolcott Ave & Polk St,TA1309000064,41.897448,-87.628722,41.871262,-87.673688,member
F6E78907CE1A21FA,classic_bike,2021-12-09 20:13:05,2021-12-09 20:27:10,Southport Ave & Clybourn Ave,TA1309000030,Clark St & Wellington Ave,TA1307000136,41.920771,-87.663712,41.9364968219,-87.6475386582,casual
9C1F2F6E50265E67,electric_bike,2021-12-18 18:14:12,2021-12-18 18:20:20,Clark St & Newport St,632,Clark St & Wellington Ave,TA1307000136,41.94454533333333,-87.654743,41.9364968219,-87.6475386582,casual
7CD421397F62EA7C,classic_bike,2021-12-12 00:37:09,2021-12-12 00:41:18,Clark St & Newport St,632,Clark St & Wellington Ave,TA1307000136,41.94454,-87.654678,41.9364968219,-87.6475386582,casual
"
all_trips <- read_csv(theData)
```


```
```{r create new columns}
all_trips$date <- as.Date(all_trips$started_at) #The default format is yyyy-mm-dd
all_trips$month <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%m")
all_trips$day <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%d")
all_trips$year <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%Y")
all_trips$day_of_week <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%A")
```
### Convert "ride_length" from Factor to numeric so we can run calculations on the data

```{rconvert to numeric}
all_trips <- all_trips %>% 
  mutate(ride_length = as.numeric(ride_length))
is.numeric(all_trips$ride_length)
```

### Remove "bad" data
The dataframe includes a few hundred entries when bikes were taken out of docks and checked for quality by Cyclistic or ride_length was negative We will create a new version of the dataframe (v2) since data is being removed

```{r remove bad data}
all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$from_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0), ]
```
````

produces an error when knitting the R markdown notebook:

```
Quitting from lines 281-282 (Cyclistic_analysis_R_markdown.Rmd) 
Error in `vectbl_as_row_location()`:
! Can't subset rows with `!...`.
✖ Logical subscript `!...` must be size 1 or 5733451, not 0.
Backtrace:
  1. ...[]
  9. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
 10. vctrs:::stop_indicator_size(...)
Warning message:
In get_engine(options$engine) :
  Unknown language engine 'rconvert' (must be registered via knit_engines$set()).

Execution halted
  9. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
 10. vctrs:::stop_indicator_size(...)
Warning message:
In get_engine(options$engine) :
  Unknown language engine 'rconvert' (must be registered via knit_engines$set()).

Execution halted
```

How do I correct this

I have try checking other sites to understand the nature of this error with very little success.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data? i am not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: It appears that the code chunk you're looking at is not the one that raises the error. You posted: `...  all_trips$ride_length<0 ...` while the error message reads `... !all_trips$ride_length <= 0 ...`. Naming your code chunks will make debugging easier: https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/document-your-science/rmarkdown-code-chunks-comments-knitr/

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors that cause the code chunk at the bottom of the OP to fail.

First, the section of code to convert `trip_length` to numeric generates an error because of a typo, `r convert-to-numeric` starts with `rconvert`.

````
```{rconvert to numeric}
all_trips <- all_trips %>% 
  mutate(ride_length = as.numeric(ride_length))
is.numeric(all_trips$ride_length)
```
````

Knitr simply skips the code block because it does not recognize an `rconvert` engine.

This hides another error, the fact that in the input Kaggle data set there is no column `ride_length`.  Due to this subtlety, the code at line 155 fails cause `all_trips$ride_length` does not exist.

To correct the error, we need to do two things. First, back in the `r create new columns` code block we add a line of code to calculate `trip_length`.

```
all_trips$ride_length <- all_trips$ended_at - all_trips$started_at
```

Second, the data that I downloaded from Kaggle.com uses `start_station_name` and `end_station_name`, which is apparently different than the data used in the OP. The trip start and end times are also called `started_at` and `ended_at` in the data I downloaded.

Therefore, we need to change the line that selects out the invalid trips to the following:

```
all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0), ]
```

With these corrections, the minimal reproducible example will render output correctly. We print the last section of the rendered file to demonstrate that it was rendered without error.
[image]

A corrected version of the entire script posted by the OP looks like this:

````
---
title: "Google Data Analytics"
author: "ifechi mafiana"
date: "2022-12-26"
output: html_document
---


## Cyclistic Bike analysis
**The plots of the Cyclistic bike rides data analysis shows the comparison between annual members and casual riders bike usage**

Data source for the stackoverflow question is a [Kaggle.com data set]("https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/carlosmmuozebratt/divvytripdata-may2022-to-september2022?resource=download"). 

Original SO question is [here.]("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74922366/i-keep-getting-error-in-knitting-r-markdown-notebook)


### Setting up my environment

```{r set-up-environment}
# setwd("C:/Users/olatu/Documents/R Programming/Cyclistic_tripdata")
```

```{r load-packages}
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
```

### Collect Data and Upload data

```{r load-12-months-tripdata}
#dec_2021 <- read_csv("202112-divvy-tripdata.csv")
#jan_2022 <- read_csv("202201_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#feb_2022 <- read_csv("202202_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#mar_2022 <- read_csv("202203_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#apr_2022 <- read_csv("202204_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#may_2022 <- read_csv("202205_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#jun_2022 <- read_csv("202206_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#jul_2022 <- read_csv("202207_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#aug_2022 <- read_csv("202208_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#sep_2022 <- read_csv("202209_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#oct_2022 <- read_csv("202210_divvy_tripdata.csv")
#nov_2022 <- read_csv("202211_divvy_tripdata.csv")

# Use first 100 rows of data from Dec 2021 file 
theData <- "ride_id,rideable_type,started_at,ended_at,start_station_name,start_station_id,end_station_name,end_station_id,start_lat,start_lng,end_lat,end_lng,member_casual
46F8167220E4431F,electric_bike,2021-12-07 15:06:07,2021-12-07 15:13:42,Laflin St & Cullerton St,13307,Morgan St & Polk St,TA1307000130,41.854833,-87.66366033333334,41.8719685,-87.65096533333333,member
73A77762838B32FD,electric_bike,2021-12-11 03:43:29,2021-12-11 04:10:23,LaSalle Dr & Huron St,KP1705001026,Clarendon Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000119,41.894405166666665,-87.632331,41.967968,-87.650001,casual
4CF42452054F59C5,electric_bike,2021-12-15 23:10:28,2021-12-15 23:23:14,Halsted St & North Branch St,KA1504000117,Broadway & Barry Ave,13137,41.89935716666667,-87.64852183333333,41.93758231600629,-87.6440978050232,member
3278BA87BF698339,classic_bike,2021-12-26 16:16:10,2021-12-26 16:30:53,Halsted St & North Branch St,KA1504000117,LaSalle Dr & Huron St,KP1705001026,41.89939028549696,-87.64854490756989,41.894877,-87.632326,member
6FF54232576A3B73,electric_bike,2021-12-30 11:31:05,2021-12-30 11:51:21,Leavitt St & Chicago Ave,18058,Clark St & Drummond Pl,TA1307000142,41.89557883333333,-87.68202383333333,41.931248,-87.644336,member
93E8D79490E3AB11,classic_bike,2021-12-01 18:28:36,2021-12-01 18:38:03,Wabash Ave & 16th St,SL-012,Wells St & Polk St,SL-011,41.860384,-87.625813,41.872596,-87.633502,member
135518383C9CACF0,electric_bike,2021-12-09 15:49:51,2021-12-09 15:55:49,Laflin St & Cullerton St,13307,Halsted St & Maxwell St,TA1309000001,41.8548755,-87.66365216666667,41.86482733333333,-87.64709983333333,member
CDF93C212EA9B261,classic_bike,2021-12-31 13:02:08,2021-12-31 13:20:59,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Ashland Ave & Lake St,13073,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.88592,-87.66717,casual
0FCA94C5F26535C8,electric_bike,2021-12-20 14:25:53,2021-12-20 14:35:48,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Ogden Ave & Chicago Ave,TA1305000020,41.885915518,-87.631485343,41.896362458,-87.6540612729,member
8E913048B7BCAA47,classic_bike,2021-12-19 16:58:32,2021-12-19 17:15:01,Fairbanks St & Superior St,18003,Lincoln Park Conservatory,LP-,41.895748,-87.620104,41.92393131136619,-87.63582453131676,member
E3689BB4C54E030A,classic_bike,2021-12-29 10:40:44,2021-12-29 11:01:45,Michigan Ave & 18th St,13150,Michigan Ave & 18th St,13150,41.857813,-87.62455,41.857813,-87.62455,member
293B0FE2F7F99DE2,electric_bike,2021-12-21 12:05:20,2021-12-21 12:08:10,Dearborn St & Van Buren St,624,Dearborn St & Van Buren St,624,41.876252651,-87.629443526,41.876268,-87.629155,member
E02FB049C19238C7,classic_bike,2021-12-14 08:07:53,2021-12-14 08:13:06,LaSalle Dr & Huron St,KP1705001026,Rush St & Hubbard St,KA1503000044,41.894877,-87.632326,41.890173,-87.626185,casual
5907837A6F7AA0B7,electric_bike,2021-12-22 08:40:41,2021-12-22 08:43:40,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,Clark St & Touhy Ave,RP-007,42.012708,-87.66613566666666,42.01256011541,-87.6743671152,casual
A9765C45F5C7571B,classic_bike,2021-12-17 08:46:26,2021-12-17 08:50:18,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,Clark St & Touhy Ave,RP-007,42.012701,-87.666058,42.01256011541,-87.6743671152,casual
AFFEDF52749D0EE5,classic_bike,2021-12-06 08:44:04,2021-12-06 08:48:36,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,Clark St & Touhy Ave,RP-007,42.012701,-87.666058,42.01256011541,-87.6743671152,casual
403B1425A552627A,electric_bike,2021-12-03 08:46:31,2021-12-03 08:48:40,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,Clark St & Touhy Ave,RP-007,42.01278633333333,-87.66606166666666,42.0126045,-87.674227,casual
1F890212968B33FD,classic_bike,2021-12-18 09:17:17,2021-12-18 09:29:05,Wells St & Huron St,TA1306000012,Aberdeen St & Monroe St,13156,41.894722,-87.634362,41.880419,-87.655519,member
F05028CCBDD22947,docked_bike,2021-12-04 11:44:37,2021-12-04 11:57:54,Wilton Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1307000134,Halsted St & Roscoe St,TA1309000025,41.94018,-87.65304,41.94367,-87.64895,casual
B55A7BFC64E93A57,electric_bike,2021-12-08 09:34:04,2021-12-08 09:41:01,Wilton Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1307000134,Halsted St & Roscoe St,TA1309000025,41.94008016666667,-87.65298683333333,41.94372083333333,-87.64885633333333,member
A97968863BBCE05C,classic_bike,2021-12-09 16:01:07,2021-12-09 16:21:01,Aberdeen St & Randolph St,18062,Walsh Park,18067,41.884114,-87.654264,41.91461,-87.667968,member
E07A177659BC448F,electric_bike,2021-12-11 17:08:07,2021-12-11 17:15:10,Dodge Ave & Church St,600,Evanston Civic Center,661,42.04830366666667,-87.69849883333333,42.057044,-87.686554,casual
2B5A05BD74955D2A,classic_bike,2021-12-10 08:48:55,2021-12-10 08:52:31,Federal St & Polk St,SL-008,Wabash Ave & Roosevelt Rd,TA1305000002,41.87207763285,-87.6295437729,41.867227,-87.625961,member
50A1154F93E6A55E,electric_bike,2021-12-25 08:48:36,2021-12-25 09:15:09,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,Clinton St & Jackson Blvd,638,41.90043033333333,-87.69670666666667,41.878316611830684,-87.64098107814789,member
A470CE16359A50A2,classic_bike,2021-12-18 19:32:39,2021-12-18 19:38:48,Fairbanks St & Superior St,18003,New St & Illinois St,TA1306000013,41.895748,-87.620104,41.890847040623804,-87.61861681938171,member
0FB2A64EE77B56E7,classic_bike,2021-12-11 23:25:56,2021-12-11 23:47:48,Dodge Ave & Church St,600,Oakley Ave & Touhy Ave,RP-004,42.048308,-87.698224,42.012342,-87.688243,member
E7E15D54DD72AC73,electric_bike,2021-12-03 19:34:27,2021-12-03 19:48:21,N Green St & W Lake St,20246.0,Damen Ave & Wabansia Ave,20.0,41.89,-87.65,41.91,-87.68,casual
4D83C1605F5F918E,electric_bike,2021-12-29 11:48:18,2021-12-29 12:00:59,State St & Pearson St,TA1307000061,N Carpenter St & W Lake St,20251.0,41.897466,-87.62874716666667,41.89,-87.65,casual
06A16531D95759A1,classic_bike,2021-12-14 18:55:01,2021-12-14 18:58:01,Wilton Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1307000134,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.94018,-87.65304,41.94454,-87.654678,member
28C14B8496B5DD70,electric_bike,2021-12-29 20:25:09,2021-12-29 21:12:03,Lake Park Ave & 56th St,TA1309000063,MLK Jr Dr & 47th St,TA1308000007,41.793267166666666,-87.58784083333333,41.809851,-87.616279,member
8ACF980C651AB448,classic_bike,2021-12-09 20:19:40,2021-12-09 20:33:22,Halsted St & Wrightwood Ave,TA1309000061,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.929143,-87.649077,41.94454,-87.654678,member
D1910A373A3A0BB9,classic_bike,2021-12-10 02:20:46,2021-12-10 02:25:28,Sheffield Ave & Wellington Ave,TA1307000052,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.9362534831413,-87.65266209840775,41.94454,-87.654678,member
9BA29005E96FCC49,classic_bike,2021-12-04 17:20:51,2021-12-04 17:31:33,Lincoln Ave & Waveland Ave,13253,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.948797,-87.675278,41.94454,-87.654678,member
AC31CCD9B07FF5F9,classic_bike,2021-12-04 21:34:55,2021-12-04 21:44:55,Lincoln Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1309000042,Clark St & Newport St,632,41.939365,-87.668385,41.94454,-87.654678,casual
CC027A7D6A217B97,electric_bike,2021-12-05 10:39:16,2021-12-05 10:44:49,Loomis St & Jackson Blvd,13206,Wood St & Taylor St (Temp),13285,41.877955166666666,-87.66199466666667,41.87000616666667,-87.67378283333333,member
0F548320DAB8D329,electric_bike,2021-12-13 11:02:49,2021-12-13 11:14:54,Fairbanks St & Superior St,18003,Streeter Dr & Grand Ave,13022,41.896165833333335,-87.62022,41.892278,-87.612043,casual
4B67968FF3B2B856,classic_bike,2021-12-01 00:28:14,2021-12-01 00:45:56,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Calumet Ave & 21st St,15546,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.85418424947,-87.6191537415,casual
13ECACF914AD20A1,electric_bike,2021-12-09 18:08:46,2021-12-09 18:20:55,State St & Pearson St,TA1307000061,Streeter Dr & Grand Ave,13022,41.89745466666667,-87.62857033333333,41.892278,-87.612043,casual
8B2078CF8767BC69,classic_bike,2021-12-20 09:35:37,2021-12-20 09:46:30,Wabash Ave & 16th St,SL-012,LaSalle St & Washington St,13006,41.860384,-87.625813,41.882664,-87.63253,member
3DCFF37E2BEDCEAA,electric_bike,2021-12-10 10:34:26,2021-12-10 10:42:30,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,,,42.0128285,-87.66592533333333,42.0,-87.66,member
8F0F71A8AB4D31CE,electric_bike,2021-12-03 17:27:21,2021-12-03 17:36:48,Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave,525,,,42.01275316666667,-87.66610816666666,42.0,-87.66,casual
89AD350CD31D0510,classic_bike,2021-12-13 11:47:12,2021-12-13 11:58:42,Broadway & Granville Ave,15571,Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave,TA1308000021,41.9947796884,-87.6602845349,41.968812,-87.657659,member
CDA946785B295248,classic_bike,2021-12-06 08:58:57,2021-12-06 09:07:53,Wabash Ave & 16th St,SL-012,Michigan Ave & 14th St,TA1307000124,41.860384,-87.625813,41.864059,-87.623727,member
A4A59AAD9459329F,classic_bike,2021-12-19 11:03:13,2021-12-19 11:11:29,Southport Ave & Clybourn Ave,TA1309000030,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.920771,-87.663712,41.9256018819,-87.6537080423,member
6ECCE59D288A5CCF,classic_bike,2021-12-19 11:40:19,2021-12-19 11:48:14,Southport Ave & Clybourn Ave,TA1309000030,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.920771,-87.663712,41.9256018819,-87.6537080423,member
8C4488C4A94BB147,electric_bike,2021-12-20 13:34:41,2021-12-20 14:07:08,Aberdeen St & Monroe St,13156,Central Park Ave & Ogden Ave,15685,41.880546808,-87.655724049,41.854063503874464,-87.71511733531952,member
6A96D37D4F39C586,classic_bike,2021-12-16 08:16:33,2021-12-16 08:25:27,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Canal St & Madison St,13341,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.882091,-87.639833,member
24BB294225E94AC1,classic_bike,2021-12-20 15:11:04,2021-12-20 15:20:06,Campbell Ave & Montrose Ave,15623,Washtenaw Ave & Lawrence Ave,KA1504000080,41.96152593287,-87.6911650414,41.968987,-87.696027,member
90FA2B7BB19CF096,classic_bike,2021-12-29 20:11:00,2021-12-29 20:43:57,Canal St & Monroe St,13056,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.88169,-87.63953,41.9256018819,-87.6537080423,member
657E9CFD79B95AE8,electric_bike,2021-12-02 00:51:09,2021-12-02 01:04:05,N Green St & W Lake St,20246.0,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.89,-87.65,41.925649,-87.65371683333333,casual
D3632D691E8F813C,electric_bike,2021-12-04 13:06:46,2021-12-04 13:10:53,Burling St & Diversey Pkwy,TA1309000036,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.93305766666667,-87.64765216666666,41.925556666666665,-87.6536585,member
98F5A6F00C8555F2,electric_bike,2021-12-03 17:20:26,2021-12-03 17:25:23,Ashland Ave & Wrightwood Ave,13296,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.9288585,-87.66863883333333,41.925589,-87.65368433333333,member
B91BB790F7579041,classic_bike,2021-12-24 11:06:26,2021-12-24 11:12:43,Southport Ave & Clybourn Ave,TA1309000030,Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave,TA1306000016,41.920771,-87.663712,41.9256018819,-87.6537080423,casual
1CF72E362EFE630D,electric_bike,2021-12-06 13:02:00,2021-12-06 13:11:11,Lincoln Ave & Belmont Ave,TA1309000042,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.939370394,-87.668308496,41.967056394,-87.679019332,casual
0221F6E40799B545,electric_bike,2021-12-18 22:51:12,2021-12-18 22:58:52,Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave,TA1308000021,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.9688455,-87.65766416666666,41.967094,-87.679028,member
011DA6BBC01F7E4D,classic_bike,2021-12-15 17:24:27,2021-12-15 17:40:10,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Michigan Ave & 14th St,TA1307000124,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.864059,-87.623727,member
CEFAFD7AFF3196EE,classic_bike,2021-12-26 14:46:11,2021-12-26 15:08:52,Lakefront Trail & Bryn Mawr Ave,KA1504000152,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.98403669612,-87.6523104689,41.967094,-87.679028,casual
F6CBEFD434F8E287,classic_bike,2021-12-18 22:40:14,2021-12-18 23:01:50,Clark St & Newport St,632,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.94454,-87.654678,41.967094,-87.679028,casual
610FFD9351696397,classic_bike,2021-12-27 15:29:05,2021-12-27 16:26:10,Walsh Park,18067,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,41.91461,-87.667968,41.967094,-87.679028,casual
7176000CF625B000,classic_bike,2021-12-15 20:36:45,2021-12-15 20:56:54,Latrobe Ave & Chicago Ave,642,Latrobe Ave & Chicago Ave,642,41.894745,-87.756895,41.894745,-87.756895,casual
6122422CF59F1F67,electric_bike,2021-12-12 14:09:44,2021-12-12 14:50:15,2112 W Peterson Ave,KA1504000155,2112 W Peterson Ave,KA1504000155,41.99112733333333,-87.68361483333334,41.991178,-87.683593,casual
5FCDBE49D4E0C200,classic_bike,2021-12-12 13:12:48,2021-12-12 13:37:31,Kildare Ave & Montrose Ave,KA1706005015,Wolcott (Ravenswood) Ave & Montrose Ave,TA1307000144,41.96108,-87.73569,41.961406,-87.676169,casual
21E8C75412330B79,electric_bike,2021-12-14 17:50:19,2021-12-14 18:16:13,N Carpenter St & W Lake St,20251.0,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.89,-87.65,41.900363,-87.696704,casual
1DEF50889E9AEBAA,electric_bike,2021-12-03 16:35:36,2021-12-03 16:56:21,Damen Ave & Grand Ave,TA1308000006,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.89127383333334,-87.67688483333333,41.90031033333333,-87.696708,member
C52AE4225D48325D,electric_bike,2021-12-04 08:01:57,2021-12-04 08:14:05,Emerald Ave & 28th St,TA1307000153,Hoyne Ave & 34th St,337,41.84358666666667,-87.6454565,41.83,-87.68,member
B5B219C88CA6AF2E,classic_bike,2021-12-10 13:41:52,2021-12-10 13:54:44,Elizabeth St & 59th St,647,Ashland Ave & 66th St,16950,41.789696880483376,-87.65469789505005,41.774074,-87.663815,member
94F6992B0BDFAAA1,electric_bike,2021-12-03 20:16:01,2021-12-03 20:33:14,Orleans St & Chestnut St (NEXT Apts),620,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.898133333333334,-87.63740616666666,41.900313,-87.69669016666667,member
6AC61ECBD3F40AC3,electric_bike,2021-12-17 23:28:12,2021-12-17 23:31:54,Leavitt St & Division St,658,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.903012333333336,-87.68369916666667,41.900363,-87.696704,member
1C74CD5B7E1ACB16,electric_bike,2021-12-18 18:28:09,2021-12-18 18:50:41,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.8859895,-87.63141283333333,41.900363,-87.696704,casual
86115CC031D84228,electric_bike,2021-12-17 08:00:01,2021-12-17 08:20:28,Sheffield Ave & Wellington Ave,TA1307000052,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.936349869,-87.652525187,41.900363,-87.696704,casual
9782815F2CC9E24F,classic_bike,2021-12-10 08:12:44,2021-12-10 08:22:28,Honore St & Division St,TA1305000034,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.903119,-87.673935,41.900363,-87.696704,member
120241F9439BE1B9,classic_bike,2021-12-02 12:11:45,2021-12-02 12:28:19,Laflin St & Cullerton St,13307,Halsted St & Roosevelt Rd,TA1305000017,41.85491457576575,-87.66355991363525,41.867324,-87.648625,member
41AC50E187DE1A86,classic_bike,2021-12-06 14:04:57,2021-12-06 14:07:51,Aberdeen St & Monroe St,13156,Green St & Madison St,TA1307000120,41.880419,-87.655519,41.881892,-87.648789,member
65F507B9C9FED0B5,classic_bike,2021-12-24 12:50:14,2021-12-24 12:51:43,State St & Randolph St,TA1305000029,Daley Center Plaza,TA1306000010,41.88462107257936,-87.62783423066139,41.884241,-87.629634,member
A42CBACBBB0A5F27,electric_bike,2021-12-23 13:06:11,2021-12-23 13:07:38,State St & Randolph St,TA1305000029,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.884563,-87.627875,41.884576228,-87.63188991,member
C50FCC0636821A77,electric_bike,2021-12-21 14:25:47,2021-12-21 14:46:51,Laflin St & Cullerton St,13307,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.85482283333333,-87.66370816666667,41.884576228,-87.63188991,casual
86A06B8C23F54400,electric_bike,2021-12-01 20:16:23,2021-12-01 20:25:19,Wells St & Huron St,TA1306000012,Green St & Madison St,TA1307000120,41.89496416666667,-87.6343905,41.88212883333333,-87.6487835,member
21E3BD0217503F94,electric_bike,2021-12-13 09:07:29,2021-12-13 09:13:36,State St & Pearson St,TA1307000061,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.89708233333333,-87.628757,41.884576228,-87.63188991,member
BA5A950CEDA7D465,classic_bike,2021-12-15 17:12:23,2021-12-15 17:13:39,Clark St & Lake St,KA1503000012,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.88602082773,-87.6308760584,41.884576228,-87.63188991,casual
DF6553F5009A743C,electric_bike,2021-12-09 06:32:42,2021-12-09 06:45:26,Washtenaw Ave & Ogden Ave,KA1504000109,Green St & Madison St,TA1307000120,41.86187916666667,-87.6935635,41.881781833333335,-87.64908066666666,casual
48C9ACB2054E5DC5,electric_bike,2021-12-07 18:52:54,2021-12-07 18:56:50,LaSalle St & Washington St,13006,Green St & Madison St,TA1307000120,41.882658166666666,-87.63257866666666,41.881865166666664,-87.648443,member
B6DE20D10BB7F2A2,classic_bike,2021-12-07 08:14:49,2021-12-07 08:21:15,Columbus Dr & Randolph St,13263,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.884728,-87.619521,41.884576228,-87.63188991,member
E9BDAA92128EB17A,docked_bike,2021-12-14 11:16:15,2021-12-14 11:24:25,Indiana Ave & Roosevelt Rd,SL-005,State St & Van Buren St,TA1305000035,41.867888,-87.623041,41.877181,-87.627844,casual
2318305579BEF4BC,electric_bike,2021-12-01 13:12:17,2021-12-01 13:18:45,N Green St & W Lake St,20246.0,Clark St & Randolph St,TA1305000030,41.89,-87.65,41.88519133333333,-87.63171466666667,member
CBCCD6345A1A04C1,electric_bike,2021-12-16 17:10:14,2021-12-16 17:24:01,Milwaukee Ave & Grand Ave,13033,California Ave & Cortez St,17660,41.891658,-87.64808316666667,41.900363,-87.696704,member
620201B2E4B4A936,electric_bike,2021-12-27 05:34:05,2021-12-27 05:55:53,Clark St & Newport St,632,McClurg Ct & Erie St,KA1503000041,41.94457666666667,-87.65482666666666,41.894503,-87.617854,member
B40421B9789D7A9D,electric_bike,2021-12-21 05:36:34,2021-12-21 05:41:52,Halsted St & North Branch St,KA1504000117,Halsted St & Clybourn Ave,331,41.89932683333333,-87.64850733333333,41.909668,-87.648128,casual
48FEC42831404CCC,classic_bike,2021-12-07 22:58:33,2021-12-07 23:07:12,Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave,TA1308000021,Broadway & Ridge Ave,15578,41.968812,-87.657659,41.9840446107,-87.6602738295,member
744D14BD03CEB1E8,classic_bike,2021-12-14 16:03:08,2021-12-14 16:08:34,Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave,TA1308000021,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.968812,-87.657659,41.978353,-87.659753,member
CD9E7DF9BE191A94,electric_bike,2021-12-18 12:32:00,2021-12-18 12:59:49,Fairbanks St & Superior St,18003,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.8957795,-87.62063883333333,41.978353,-87.659753,member
DAFFB8138DA2B444,classic_bike,2021-12-05 10:06:32,2021-12-05 10:30:59,Damen Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000158,Broadway & Ridge Ave,15578,41.967094,-87.679028,41.9840446107,-87.6602738295,casual
14CF12D2CC28AFDD,classic_bike,2021-12-15 20:24:34,2021-12-15 20:48:42,Clark St & Newport St,632,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.94454,-87.654678,41.978353,-87.659753,casual
D6CDF4784BD2C926,electric_bike,2021-12-31 12:27:08,2021-12-31 12:34:26,Sheridan Rd & Montrose Ave,TA1307000107,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.961522333333335,-87.654598,41.978353,-87.659753,member
A09709F0C2EBC78B,classic_bike,2021-12-05 17:40:26,2021-12-05 17:47:59,Clarendon Ave & Leland Ave,TA1307000119,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.967968,-87.650001,41.978353,-87.659753,member
EE59FE91B61BCCC8,classic_bike,2021-12-19 11:12:34,2021-12-19 11:16:07,Clark St & Berwyn Ave,KA1504000146,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.978030622486564,-87.66856491565704,41.978353,-87.659753,member
1293FC6A35A690EB,classic_bike,2021-12-16 06:22:43,2021-12-16 06:25:17,Clark St & Berwyn Ave,KA1504000146,Broadway & Berwyn Ave,13109,41.978030622486564,-87.66856491565704,41.978353,-87.659753,member
3CBE482E55A4F4A6,classic_bike,2021-12-13 07:26:13,2021-12-13 08:05:11,State St & Pearson St,TA1307000061,Wolcott Ave & Polk St,TA1309000064,41.897448,-87.628722,41.871262,-87.673688,member
F6E78907CE1A21FA,classic_bike,2021-12-09 20:13:05,2021-12-09 20:27:10,Southport Ave & Clybourn Ave,TA1309000030,Clark St & Wellington Ave,TA1307000136,41.920771,-87.663712,41.9364968219,-87.6475386582,casual
9C1F2F6E50265E67,electric_bike,2021-12-18 18:14:12,2021-12-18 18:20:20,Clark St & Newport St,632,Clark St & Wellington Ave,TA1307000136,41.94454533333333,-87.654743,41.9364968219,-87.6475386582,casual
7CD421397F62EA7C,classic_bike,2021-12-12 00:37:09,2021-12-12 00:41:18,Clark St & Newport St,632,Clark St & Wellington Ave,TA1307000136,41.94454,-87.654678,41.9364968219,-87.6475386582,casual
"
all_trips <- read_csv(theData)

```

### Inspecting the column names

```{r inspecting-column-names}
#colnames(dec_2021)
#colnames(jan_2022)
#colnames(feb_2022)
#colnames(mar_2022)
#colnames(apr_2022)
#colnames(may_2022)
#colnames(jun_2022)
#colnames(jul_2022)
#colnames(aug_2022)
#colnames(sep_2022)
#colnames(oct_2022)
#colnames(nov_2022)
```
### Stack individual quarter's data frames into one big data frame
```{r merge-dataframes}
# all_trips <- bind_rows(dec_2021, jan_2022, feb_2022, mar_2022, apr_2022, may_2022, jun_2022, jul_2022, aug_2022, sep_2022, oct_2022, nov_2022)
```
```{r create-new-columns}
# all_trips$date <- as.Date(all_trips$start_time) #The default format is yyyy-mm-dd
all_trips$date <- as.Date(all_trips$started_at)
all_trips$month <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%m")
all_trips$day <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%d")
all_trips$year <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%Y")
all_trips$day_of_week <- format(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%A")
all_trips$ride_length <- all_trips$ended_at - all_trips$started_at #added 
```
### Convert "ride_length" from Factor to numeric so we can run calculations on the data

```{r convert-to-numeric}
all_trips <- all_trips %>% 
  mutate(ride_length = as.numeric(ride_length))
is.numeric(all_trips$ride_length)
```

### Remove "bad" data
The dataframe includes a few hundred entries when bikes were taken out of docks and checked for quality by Cyclistic or ride_length was negative We will create a new version of the dataframe (v2) since data is being removed

```{r remove-bad-data}
#all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$from_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0), ]
all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0), ]
```

### View the cleaned dataset

Note: because `View()` requires a graphical user interface, we can't use it when knitting an R Markdown file. 

```{r view-dataset}

# View(all_trips_v2)
```

## Conduct descriptive analysis

### Descriptive analysis on ride_length (all figures in seconds)

```{r quick-summary-ride-length}
summary(all_trips_v2$ride_length)
```

### Compare members and casual users

In this section, we needed to change `usertype` to `member_casual` based on data from Kaggle. 

```{r compare-casual-and-members-ride-length}
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual, FUN = mean)
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual, FUN = median)
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual, FUN = max)
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual, FUN = min)
```

### The average ride time by each day for members vs casual users

```{r average-ride-time-of-users}
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual + all_trips_v2$day_of_week, FUN = mean)
```

### Notice that the days of the week are out of order. Let's fix that.

```{r correct-the-days-of-the-week}
all_trips_v2$day_of_week <- ordered(all_trips_v2$day_of_week, levels=c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
```

### Now, let's run the average ride time by each day for members vs casual users

```{r average-ride-duration-of-users}
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual + all_trips_v2$day_of_week, FUN = mean)
```

### analyze ridership data by type and weekday

Changed `start_time` to `started_at` based on data received from Kaggle.com. 
                                                           
```{r analyze-ride-data-by-type-and-weekday}
plot1 <- all_trips_v2 %>% 
  mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>%  #creates weekday field using wday()
  group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>%  #groups by usertype and weekday
  summarise(number_of_rides = n()                                       #calculates the number of rides and average duration 
            ,average_duration = mean(ride_length)) %>%                 # calculates the average duration
  arrange(member_casual, weekday) %>%                                     # sorts
  drop_na()
```
````